# How to route in method on json request

Tags: c#, json, api, .net-core

I am writing a server on Core for a client that uses the API. He has no routes. There is only IP and Port. But in json body, there is a name for the method that I have to implement.

Request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1 
Accept: application/json 
Api-Version: 10 
Authorization: Bearer 111111111
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Host: 127.0.0.1:5050 
Content-Length: 104 
Connection: Close
{  
    "UniqueRequestId": null,  
    "Method": "GetPumpState",  
    "Data": {    "PumpNumber": 1  } 
}
```

I have no idea how to implement this. How to get the tag "Method" from the request, make routing to the method in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

When you would like to go with controller routes. You can use [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to intercept the request and transform your `Body` routing into the controller route.

You should parse request body and update the context with `Method` value to match the controller route, which should start with `/`. Then you can replace the current body stream with `Data` if you don't want to bother with extra data in your controller.

Following code can give you some idea. It transforms the request body and sends only content of data to controller route.

```cs
public class RouteMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<RouteMiddleWare> _logger;

    public RouteMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<RouteMiddleWare> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            var requestBody = new MemoryStream();
            context.Request.Body.CopyTo(requestBody);
            requestBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(requestBody);

            try
            {
                var body = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(body);
                context.Request.Path = request.Method;


                context.Request.Body =
                    new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.Data)));

                using (requestBody) _logger.LogInformation("Request body stream has been replaced");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"Failed to apply route from body: {ex.Message}");
                context.Request.Body = requestBody;
            }

            context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        await _next.Invoke(context);

    }

    class Request
    {
        public string UniqueRequestId { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public dynamic Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*On the other hand, it would be better to change the client code to use proper paths.*